# Send a file via HTTP POST UploadFile Error: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, system.net

I am trying to post an XML file to an URL that was given to me:

https://54.xx.xx.xxx/mycompany/path

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
  client.UploadFile(url, filePath);
}
```

However, I get this error:

"The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."

When I open up the URL, it returns a page saying "Running" however, I see the lock with an X on it, with error: "The Identity of this website has not been verified".

Could this be the problem? I need some light please.

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703272/could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-ssl-tls-secure-channel-soap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that your site uses SSL certificate authenticity and for some reason, its application verifies authenticity and this does not allow the operation run due to "lack of security"

possibly its certificate expired?