# SSL/TLS error when using youtube data api v3 for windows 8 - ARM

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

When using [Google.Apis.YouTube.v3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.YouTube.v3/) for Windows 8 store app and running on Surface RT tablet (ARM), I get this error when accessing YouTube content:

> Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS.
>        Inner exception: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Is there any solution for this problem?

PS: The same APIs work fine on windows phone 8.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my Surface time was not correct, so it was giving certificate issue. [This post helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15028383/1158845).