# Not able to download file from Dropbox because failing to connect with SSL/TLS channel through WebClient in C#

Tags: ssl, windows-services, dropbox, webclient

Trying to download an executable file from Dropbox's private folder to PC in a Windows Service using `WebClient.DownloadFile()`. But it is throwing error
**The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.**

What weired is, error occurring only in Windows XP (SP2) and not in Windows 7, 8 & 8.1. (Not tested in XP SP3 and Vista yet.)

Tried with:

- `WebClient.UseDefaultCredentials` is `true`.
- `WebClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials` or `CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials`.
- `http://` in URL instead of `https://`.

Comment: Is it possibly due to the SSL connection requiring a later version of SSL / TLS than XP supports?  The server specifies what valid types of security are allowed on the connection.

Comment: @lukevp can we fix it through the code itself?

Comment: For reference, as a matter of security, Dropbox did stop supporting SSLv3 some time ago. You should make sure you're using >=TLSv1.0.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I solved it myself. Answer from [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703272/could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-ssl-tls-secure-channel-soap), which has more votes, helped me to solve it.

My sample as follows:

```
public static void DownloadFileFromDropbox(string dropboxUrl, string file_name)
    WebClient webclient = null;
    try
    {
        webclient = new WebClient();

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidRemoteCertificate);

        if (File.Exists(UpdatesDirStr + file_name))
        {
            File.Delete(UpdatesDirStr + file_name);
        }
        webclient.DownloadFile(dropboxUrl, UpdatesDirStr + file_name);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (webclient != null)
        {
            webclient.Dispose();
            webclient = null;
        }
    }
}

private static bool ValidRemoteCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    if (certificate.Subject.Contains("dropboxusercontent.com"))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (certificate.Subject.Contains("dropbox.com"))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I still wonder how does it work properly? Because `new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidRemoteCertificate)` is not taking `dropboxUrl` from anywhere. So how `X509Certificate certificate` param in `ValidRemoteCertificate` method got the correct certificate from Dropbox.com?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post your solution, it helped me out.