# connecting to TFSAPI using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, tfs-sdk

I get the following error when connecting to tfsapi using c#.I have the right credentials, url and added the dlls Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client from
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0

& System.Net too. Any suggestions of what might be causing the issue ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri url = new Uri("https://");

            NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("", "", "");

            TfsTeamProjectCollection coll = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(url, nc);

            coll.EnsureAuthenticated();

        }
    }
}
```

Error :
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Clientdll Additonal information : The underlying connection was closed. Cound not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TSL secure channel"

[image]

Comment: This answer gives you a list of things to try! ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/703285/5040941

Comment: if you're using vs2010 to connect to tfs2013 make sure you've got the sp1 patch.