# First SOAP request returns "Could not establish trust relationship for SSL/TLS secure channel"

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, soap, webservice-client

I'm sorry, but this is a weird question...

Why is the first request to a WebService returning "Could not establish trust relationship for SSL/TLS secure channel", and the next requests (all of them) are running ok?

I launch the request from my client application by clicking on a button. Then, the request is built with the proper values of address, binding and contract. The first click always returns the exception. Without closing the application, the next clicks launch the request properly.

Please don't close this question for being "unconstructive".

Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703272/could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-ssl-tls-secure-channel-soap

Comment: @AnandBhat: Doesn't sound like a duplicate because in this question the error occurs only on the first call whereas subsequent calls succeed.

Comment: @AnandBhat It's not duplicate since the error only occurs once (first request). Any clue?

Comment: If you don't have any server logs that could help, you probably need to monitor the connection with Wireshark or [System.Net trace](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webapps/archive/2012/11/05/use-system-net-trace-and-ssl-alert-protocol-to-tshoot-ssl-connection-issue.aspx) and evaluate [the initial handshake](http://www.moserware.com/2009/06/first-few-milliseconds-of-https.html)...