# Error SecureChannelFailure, could not create SSL/TLS

Tags: c#

I am calling a web service using certifcates and security protocol. The application was running fine but suddenly started giving me web exception.

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

when I checked status code, it is SecureChannelFailure and `HResult` is `2146233079`. 
The web service response is returning `NULL`.

Part of the code is as follows:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Code and exception format

Answer (score 1):

A few questions that might point you in the right direction

- Maybe the certificate you are using has expired?
- Maybe you are running the client from a different computer than before which doesn't have the trusted root of the certificate installed?
- Maybe the certificate was somehow revoked?

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when I added certs like this

```
X509Store certificatesStore = new X509Store(storeName, storeLocation);
certificatesStore.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
var matchingCertificates = certificatesStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, serialNumber, true);
request.ClientCertificates.Add(matchingCertificates );
```

Answer (score -1):

did you get a resolution to this?
I've noticed that a windows update to my windows 10 machine and the windows 2008RC servers have caused our issue.  The problem we have is that we cannot quickly change the 3rd party servers from SHA1 encrypted certs.

A way around it is to uninstall the updates listed here.
https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2016/04/29/sha1-deprecation-roadmap/

Another way around it is to add this line of code:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

Ref: [Could not establish trust relationship for SSL/TLS secure channel -- SOAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703272/could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-ssl-tls-secure-channel-soap/15483698#15483698)

However this doesn't work for us.

Comment: I also added System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls; to my code for debug only because the problem was down to my win 10 updates and the server had different updates.