# Access denied to ASP.NET WebAPI on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have to ASP.NET applications: one is a Web API and the other a MVC that makes requests to the first.

Everthing works in development (VS with IIS Express) but now I publish both applications to a production server and I can´t have access to the api using the MVC app.

I have CORS enabled on the API:

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

On the MVC app, my api base url is set to **https://localhost:44351/** and then in the IIS I have this bindings (WEB Api site):

[image: bindings]

I can make requests to the API with postman but when I run the my MVC app, I can´t make requests (and again, I could make them in development).

Thank you.

**EDIT**

Controller code example (MVC):

```
        try
        {
            var client = WebApiHttpClient.GetClient();

            var response = await client.PostAsync("Token", content);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                TokenResponse tokenResponse =
                await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<TokenResponse>();

                WebApiHttpClient.storeToken(tokenResponse);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                return Content("response.StatusCode);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return Content("Error");
        }
```

My HttpClient implementation:

```
    public const string WebApiBaseAddress = "https://localhost:44351/";

    public static HttpClient GetClient()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(WebApiBaseAddress);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new
        MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        return client;
    }
```

**EDIT 2**

InnerException message:

```
the underlying connection was closed could not establish trust relationship for the ssl/tls
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can't make requests"? What kind of response do you get?

Comment: how are you making the request? by host name or localhost

Comment: See edit please

Comment: What is the status code of the response?

Comment: Only "Error" is shown so the "catch" clause is executed.

Comment: Please add the Exception in the catch clause to see the actual error.

Comment: "An error occurred while sending the request."

Comment: And also you don't need to enable CORS because you are making request from the same domain.

Comment: I would recommend once you've got to the bottom of this to remove the CORS configuration that you have applied :).  It's a safety feature

Comment: InnerException should have more detailed exception.

Comment: Please post the FULL error dump so we can help you.

Comment: When you say it works with Postman, are you running Postman from your development machine? Or are you at the Production machine when you use Postman?

Comment: CORS was enabled so I can run an simple html page with ajax requests;
I'm running Postman from development machine. I haven't tried to run it from my server.;
InnerException message added to the question.

Comment: There is an issue with SSL certificate. Please see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703272/could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-ssl-tls-secure-channel-soap

Comment: I'm using a self signed certificate for now. This is not really the production but an test to see if the 2 apps could work together in a production environment. That being said, what could be the problem?

Comment: The problem is most likely related to server certificate validation. Please try add the following line (temporary) in Global.asax: System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback
                = ((sender, cert, chain, errors) => cert.Subject.Contains("YourServerName")); Put your server name accordingly or just localhost.

Comment: I tried with localhost and I still got the same error.

Comment: You could temporary add this line to ignore server certificate validation: ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true); If it works then add a real SSL certificate in production and remove that line.

Comment: Yap, that made it work. I'll try to get a valid SSL cert then! Thank you!

Comment: Hi, is the Answer below correct?

Comment: Yes, it is. It's a temporary fix but it works for development. The author wrote an answer. I marked it as the right one. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to summarize the discussion in the comments.
The problem was due to use of self-signed certificate in IIS for Web API application.

Temporary solution for this problem is to add this line of code in application startup class (Global.asax):

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);
```

Of course you should not use that line of code in production. In production environment you should have a valid SSL certificate.

More information can be found in this post:
[Could not establish trust relationship for SSL/TLS secure channel -- SOAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703272/could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-ssl-tls-secure-channel-soap)