# Uncatchable NullException on some URLs with DownloadString

Tags: c#, argumentnullexception, downloadstring

Is this is a bug in Visual Studio 2015 or?

```
Exception Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentNullException' in 
      mscorlib.dll ("Value cannot be null.") System.ArgumentNullException
```

The code/tutorial I was following...

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/397574/Use-Csharp-to-get-JSON-Data-from-the-Web-and-Map-i

To reproduced create a form application and add a button called "button1" and for button1_Click function add this code, http in the URL gives no error, https gives an error...

```
var w = new WebClient();
string url = "https://www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt";
var content = w.DownloadString(url);
MessageBox.Show(content);
```

Comment: In what way is this uncatchable? What specifically have you done to try to catch it?

Comment: I tried putting it in a try{ ... } catch(Exception e){ MessageBox.Show("error"); throw e; } and got no response.

Comment: And what happens in your program? Does the whole program crash? Does it continue? Does it show an unhandled exception dialog box? Also, is the exception's stack trace visible anywhere, so that you can see specifically what is throwing the exception?

Answer (score 0):

If you just use the code you have to call `https`, it will not work. Try importing these namespaces:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Net.Security;
```

Then do this for certificate verification:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
    delegate (object sender, X509Certificate certificate, 
    X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) 
    { return true; };
```

Then it should work:

```
var w = new WebClient();
string url = "https://www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt";
var content = w.DownloadString(url);
```

Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703272/could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-ssl-tls-secure-channel-soap/6613434#6613434) also to be aware of why the above approach could be dangerous.

Comment: What error do you get? And are you using the whole code I gave you?