# Intermittent error with calling a WCF service: "Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority"

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, ssl

I'm calling an svc endpoint every 5 mins. The problem is that sometimes I get this error:

> "Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority"

And other times it just runs successfully without any issues. Since this is so random and intermittent I'm not able to find the root cause.

Does anyone know what must be causing this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/703285/1554116 did you check all this?

Comment: I've read through (though have not tried) the post @RawitasKrungkaew linked to and some other posts related to this issue. I think the key in OP's case is "intermittent", which is also what I'm experiencing with calls to EWS (Exchange Web Services).

Comment: @noriMonsta exactly!!

Comment: Had any luck finding out more? I'm having the same problem where a single application makes calls that work 9/10, but sometimes I get this exception.