# How to send an HTTPS GET Request in C#

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, httpwebrequest

> Related: [how-do-i-use-webrequest-to-access-an-ssl-encrypted-site-using-https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560804/how-do-i-use-webrequest-to-access-an-ssl-encrypted-site-using-https)

How to send an HTTPS GET Request in C#?

Answer (score 78):

Add `?var1=data1&var2=data2` to the end of url to submit values to the page via GET:

```
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

string url = "https://www.example.com/scriptname.php?var1=hello";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
```

Comment: Note: this works for HTTP, I tested this code with HTTPS url and it didn't work. Going to try WebClient and see if that works with SSL

Comment: Use the address of this page. Stackoverflow runs on https and you will get a `200 OK` response `string url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/...";`. Worked!

Comment: Note that WebRequest and HttpWebRequest are no longer recommended to use for new projects.

Microsoft suggests using the newer HttpClient class instead: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use WebClient, it seems to handle SSL transparently:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx

Some troubleshooting help here:

https://clipperhouse.com/webclient-fiddler-and-ssl/

Comment: Post actual code, links can become stale.

Answer (score 2):

Simple Get Request using HttpClient Class

```
using System.Net.Http;

class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var result = httpClient.GetAsync("https://www.google.com").Result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Will this be a http call or an https call?

Comment: This will result in an exception saying SLS/TLS issue.