# how to query a https secured url with .net like https://example.com/send.aspx?msg=hi

Tags: c#, .net, https, httpwebrequest

I searched SO and google and saw only problems while doing this, unfortunately for me, my url is part of a Banks text message system and all I've got is the secured url. I have to write a test to push a message through but since Im not connected to the banks LAN I cannot test or do any sort of trail and error.

Url looks like this:

```
https://example.com/send.aspx?msg=hi
```

I'm using a windows forms .net4 application in C#.

**How do I POST with the above url using WebClient, or is there another way.**

I figure from other answers I need a certificate from the bank guys or are there options to refuse to use encryption.

---

**Update**
Awesome, thanks to Eugene Im almost there. I used web client, [like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943852/how-to-send-an-https-get-request-in-c/943875#943875) it didn't work. I changed my code to this and it worked:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(allowCert);
    string url = "https://example.com/send.aspx?msg=hi";
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader st = new StreamReader(resStream);
    Console.WriteLine(st.ReadToEnd());
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static bool allowCert(object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors error)
{
    return true;
}
```

Bonus points now for why it worked this way and what is this code doing?(It is saying "I don't care what the cert is allow it")

Comment: If the API _requires_ encryption (https suggests that it does), you can't go around it. Trying to suggests that you are attempting to do something you shouldn't...

Comment: No thats what I figured from some answers I saw, I just want to know how I could send a request to that url with webclient, would it be different from a normal http request, is the encryption handled automatically or do I need a certificate from the bank? Remember I can't test it from my dev box since I don't have access to the banks lan.(Which is where the url points,)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF the above is all that you have been given, then you don't need POST. Such request is performed using [GET method (described here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943852/how-to-send-an-https-get-request-in-c). You put the message in place of "hi" in your sample. Remember, that you need to encode the message text to "mask" any "unsafe" characters which can be misinterpreted. The best is to replace any non-alphanumeric character with it's hex code in %xx form, where xx are two digits of the hex code.

Comment: So you're saying there is no need for a certificate? The guy from the tech dept said he would send over a cert, but Ive got nothing so far. I also remember him saying I need to POST the params. Shouldn't I say `response.method = POST`??

Comment: @giddy Looks like you have not provided all relevant information in your post. You need to ask your tech.guy for detailed instructions. Guessing what he could say and mean by that saying won't help much if you can't check the guesses yourself.

Comment: @giddy Regarding certificates: unless you are instructed to use client-side authentication, you don't need your own certificate. You need to validate the certificate passed by the server, but if you use .NET Framework classes, the certificates are validated automatically for you.

Comment: Can you just check my answer again pretty please! =)

Comment: @giddy are you asking what the "allowCert" callback was doing? This callback is intended to validate server's certificate, used to secure connection and prove that you are connecting to the correct server and not the forged one. In your callback you are efficiently ignoring certificate validation altogether. While your code works, implementing validation of certificates this way makes the point of using HTTPS void. But well in your case, if message content is not secret, then the simpliest for you is not to care about certificates.

Answer (score 1):

It's not readily apparent what you are asking for in the update to your question.

HttpWebRequest is there specifically to allow you to make GET/POST/PUT/etc requests to a remote server.

The callback to allowCert is simply telling .Net to not bother validating the certificate chain.  There are several reasons why a certificate won't validate including it being out of date, or if one of the certs in the chain is out of date.  Another reason is if the certificate authority isn't trusted by the machine making the call.  Which is entirely possible if the bank issued their own cert without using a well known CA to back it.

Personally I wouldn't trust a cert that couldn't be validated.  If this is purely for testing it ought to be ok; however, if this is a production cert then I'd start talking to the bank about it.  Unfortunately a lot of banks don't seem to understand security.

Comment: Excellent! EXACTLY what I wanted! Thank you SO much!

Comment: Worse case, depending on what the bank says, is that you'll have to install the certificate authority's cert on the server making a call to the bank.  This would allow the machine to trust it... but, again, I wouldn't do this unless your server is badly out of date with it's certificate store.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but does the encryption still happen? Is everything between the server and client still encrypted?

Comment: I believe so.  I think the chain just isn't validated at all, which is it's own security issue.  For example, if there was a man in the middle attack this wouldn't be able to detect it.

Comment: ah! but a sniffer in between would see encrypted data correct?

Comment: @Giddy: Assuming a man in the middle attack, the data would be encrypted between you and the middle app.  The middle app would decrypt it then reencrypt it with the real encryption key and pass it on.  Point is, you shouldn't disable cert validation otherwise you leave yourself completely open to spoofing.