# Login to HTTPS captive portal

Tags: c#, ssl

I actually connect in my univ to the network through a captive portal at this url https://secure.arubanetworks.com/cgi-bin/login, time ago I made a program  to connect to it which worked perfect (C++ & libCurl), sending an HTTP POST with the needed "query string" such as username and password, but i think it was because there wasn't still the SSL, a X.509 Cert, that now seems to work with a GET instead of the POST that used before.

Pasting on Firefox the full url with the query string worked to me perfect, as it should, so i just tried to achieve that in a little C# program, but since i don't know what to do about the certificate (i asume there must be smth to do with it.. :P) it throws me a ProtocolError, and now i thought i should understand a bit about it first, so i'm interested in the code to achieve it, but also the way it works. :)

PS: Also would love if there's a way to set the account or the program (exe) as a callback, on the connection properties (my OS is Win7) so that once connected to the network im inmediatelly authenticated. :D

Thanks in advance for your time and help mates! ;)

```
        Uri uri = new Uri(url + "?" + postData);
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        req.Method = this.method;
        // ToDo: Something doesn't work with the cert auth I guess
        req.Proxy = null;
        req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += 
        delegate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, 
        SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            return true;
        };

        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            Stream responseStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            if (e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
            {
                HttpWebResponse response = e.Response as HttpWebResponse;
                if (response != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for an https [GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943852/how-to-send-an-https-get-request-in-c). For reference, it's related to but simpler than doing an https [POST](http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2008/05/05/send-a-https-post-request-with-c/).

There's a difference if you need an asynch approach, but I don't think that's what you need. So, you still use `HttpWebRequest` object, but there's a difference after you get to the `.method` -- all you should need is to stuff your uri into the request, and grab the response. I don't think you should manually need to mess with the proxy or credentials.

Comment: but as i said, the request is done through a GET, so shouldn't I have .method = "GET"? and then would other things still keep working???

Comment: If it's a GET, then you won't need the x-www-form-encoded. And, all you should need to do is follow the sample answer in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943852/how-to-send-an-https-get-request-in-c).

Comment: thanks you, I'll try this both asap (maybe not till 13th, since i need to be at the univ to connect) and then report the result! ;)

Comment: the answer of Bing to your links question worked perfect for me!! :D