# How to use the Companyhouse api in MVC4 C#

Tags: c#, curl, model-view-controller

I am in small trouble I need to hit the UK Companies House API from https://developer.companieshouse.gov.uk/api/.

On its website it has a nice example to do it using CURL.Since I am programming in C# MVC and need to implement the Company Search functionality that will fetch data using this API.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/943875/1865613). the C# equivalent of the Curl example (`https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/search/companies`) could look like this:

```
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

string url = "GET https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/search/companies";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Credentials = // here you have to set your authentication data
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
```