# Accept self-signed TLS/SSL certificate in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm searching for a way to validate (or bypass validation for) self-signed SSL certificates using VB.NET.  I found code to do this in C# and tried converting it into VB code, but I'm not having any luck.

Here is the C# code: [How do I use WebRequest to access an SSL encrypted site using https?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560804/how-do-i-use-webrequest-to-access-an-ssl-encrypted-site-using-https)

Here is what I tried:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates

Public Class clsSSL
    Public Function AcceptAllCertifications(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal certification As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate, ByVal chain As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain, ByVal sslPolicyErrors As System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors) As Boolean
        Return True
    End Function
End Class
```

Then before the `WebRequest` I have this line of code which gives me an error.

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
    New System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications)
```

The error message is:

> Delegate 'System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback' requires an 'AddressOf' expression or lambda expression as the only argument to its constructor.

Comment: Your `AcceptAllCertifications` is not accepting the self-signed certificate. It's accepting all certificates, even the certificates of malicious sites and attackers. You should accept of the known certificate. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5998004/850848#66559532).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In VB.Net, you need to write

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = AddressOf AcceptAllCertifications
```

Answer (score 14):

One-liner:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = _
  Function(se As Object, _
  cert As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate, _
  chain As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain, _
  sslerror As System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors) True
```

*Credits to [Robby Tendean](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/321313/Bypass-and-Restore-SSL-Certificate-Validation-in-V)*

Comment: or shorter: `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Function(s, c, h, e) True`

Answer (score 4):

All the answers here blindly accept any certificate. That's a security flaw.

When implementing [`ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidation` callback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.remotecertificatevalidationcallback) one should *validate* the certificate. E.g. by checking certificate's hash against a known value:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Security
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates
```

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
    Function(sender As Object, certificate As X509Certificate, chain As X509Chain,
             errors As SslPolicyErrors)
        Return _
            (errors = SslPolicyErrors.None) Or
            certificate.GetCertHashString(HashAlgorithmName.SHA256).Equals(
                "EB8E0B28AE064ED58CBED9DAEB46CFEB3BD7ECA67737179E3C85BC3CD09D4EEC")
    End Function
```

For the [`X509Certificate.GetCertHashString` overload that takes `HashAlgorithmName.SHA256`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.getcerthashstring#system-security-cryptography-x509certificates-x509certificate-getcerthashstring(system-security-cryptography-hashalgorithmname)), you need .NET 4.8. On older versions use [the parameter-less overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.getcerthashstring#system-security-cryptography-x509certificates-x509certificate-getcerthashstring) that returns an SHA-1 hash.

---

*Based on [Is it safe to test the X509Certificate.Thumbprint property when you know an invalid certificate is safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34642606/850848)*

*For C# version of the code, see [FtpWebRequest "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11586206/850848#66776112)*.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but this should work:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = _
      New RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AddressOf AcceptAllCertifications)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.security.remotecertificatevalidationcallback%28VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: My syntax was introduced by VB.Net 2005 (like C#'s)

Answer (score 0):

In VB.Net,

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
```

solves the less secure apps problem.

Answer (score -1):

In VB.Net

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Function(s, c, h, e) True
```