# Is it safe to test the X509Certificate.Thumbprint property when you know an invalid certificate is safe?

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, x509certificate

I'm attempting to send emails programmatically using `SmtpClient.Send`. I am currently getting an `AuthenticationException` when attempting to send the email. This is because of the certificate validation procedure failing.

I know that the certificate is the correct one, but I also understand that it's not secure to trust all certificates much like the suggestions of doing this:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += 
     (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
```

So I was wondering if testing the `Thumbprint` for a known valid certificate thumbprint is secure enough, like so:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
     (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
     {
         if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
             return true;
         else if (certificate.GetCertHashString().Equals("B1248012B10248012B"))
             return true;

         return false;
     };
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.

The thumbprint is a SHA1 hash of the certificate, and while not absolutely impossible, is extremely difficult to forge.

In technical terms, there are currently no known feasable second-preimage attacks on SHA1.

However, if in any doubt, you may store the whole certificate, perhaps using the fingerprint as a key. Then you can compare the whole certificate against your stored, trusted certificate.

Comment: Since .NET 4.8, you can validate SHA-256 fingerprint: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11586206/850848#66776112

Answer (score 2):

Thumbprint is not a part of the certificate.
In every cert tool you can see this value, but it is **computed** hash from whole certificate. Usually it is presented as SHA1, but there are no obstacles to compute as SHA256.

Morgan Simonsen wrote about this:
https://morgansimonsen.com/2013/04/16/understanding-x-509-digital-certificate-thumbprints/