# How can I upload a file to a secure FTP server that uses a self-signed certificate in Visual Basic?

Tags: .net, vb.net, ssl, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I need to upload a file to a secure FTP server that has a self signed SSL certificate.

Where can I find the certificate file?

How do I add it to the `FtpWebRequest`?

I know where the file is located on the server. It is a `.PEM` File. Does the server send the certificate to the client or do I need to place the certificate in the client application.

```
Dim request As FtpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(FTP_Address)

request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(FTP_Username, FTP_Password)

Dim cert As X509Certificate2 = ???

request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert)

request.EnableSsl = True

request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile
```

[image: The Code With The Error]

Answer (score 0):

To validate a certificate, implement [`ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidation` callback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.remotecertificatevalidationcallback) to check certificate's hash against a known value:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Security
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates
```

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
    Function(sender As Object, certificate As X509Certificate, chain As X509Chain,
             errors As SslPolicyErrors)
        Return _
            (errors = SslPolicyErrors.None) Or
            certificate.GetCertHashString(HashAlgorithmName.SHA256).Equals(
                "EB8E0B28AE064ED58CBED9DAEB46CFEB3BD7ECA67737179E3C85BC3CD09D4EEC")
    End Function
```

For the [`X509Certificate.GetCertHashString` overload that takes `HashAlgorithmName.SHA256`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.getcerthashstring#system-security-cryptography-x509certificates-x509certificate-getcerthashstring(system-security-cryptography-hashalgorithmname)), you need .NET 4.8. On older versions use [the parameter-less overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.getcerthashstring#system-security-cryptography-x509certificates-x509certificate-getcerthashstring) that returns an SHA-1 hash.

---

*Based on [Is it safe to test the X509Certificate.Thumbprint property when you know an invalid certificate is safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34642606/850848)*

Answer (score -1):

I figured it all out this is the the code that worked correctly

```
    Private Shared Function ServerCertificateValidationCallback(sender As Object, certificate As X509Certificate, chain As X509Chain, sslPolicyErrors As SslPolicyErrors) As Boolean
    Return certificate.GetCertHashString() <> "SHA-1 Key From Certificate"
End Function

Private Sub imgExpenseFileDrop_Drop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs)

    ExpenseFilePath = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)(0)

    ExpenseFile = New FileInfo(ExpenseFilePath)

    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ExpenseFile.Extension) Then Exit Sub

    ShowFileInfo()

    Try

        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = New RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AddressOf ServerCertificateValidationCallback)


        Dim request As FtpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(FTP_Address & ExpenseFile.Name)

        request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(FTP_Username, FTP_Password)

        request.EnableSsl = True

        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

        Using FileStream As Stream = File.OpenRead(ExpenseFile.FullName),
        ftpStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
            FileStream.CopyTo(ftpStream)
        End Using



    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't you have the condition reversed? It should be `=`, not `<>`.

Comment: I wondered about that I found the code on the internet and tweaked to fit my application. It works so I haven't messed with it yet.

Comment: It does not work. If it works, then because your `"SHA-1 Key From Certificate"` does not actually match the real certificate hash (your format is probably wrong). And ultimately, your code will accept any certificate.