# How to append text to a log file with WinSCP/C#

Tags: c#, ftp, winscp-net

I'm trying to add text to a text file in a FTP server, but it overwrites it instead of appending, how to solve this ?

```cs
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
    HostName = "www.site.com",
    UserName = "name",
    Password = "pass",
    FtpSecure = FtpSecure.Explicit,

    TlsHostCertificateFingerprint = "what ever that is",
};

using (Session session = new Session())
{
    session.Open(sessionOptions);
    TransferOptions options = new TransferOptions();
    options.TransferMode = TransferMode.Ascii;
    options.OverwriteMode = OverwriteMode.Append;

    TransferOperationResult transferResult;
    transferResult = session.PutFiles(@"E:\Up\log.txt", "/log.txt", false, options);
    transferResult.Check();

    foreach (TransferEventArgs transfer in transferResult.Transfers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Upload of {0} succeeded", transfer.FileName);
    }
}
```

Found something similar here, but no solution:
https://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=25031

I don't really want to download the file, append to it, then upload it, below code worked but my credentials are visible to WireShark:

```cs
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@"Hello World.");
Uri target = new Uri("ftp://site.com/test.txt");
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(target);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.AppendFile;
request.ContentLength = data.Length;

request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("name", "pass");
using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't appending text. Try this.

```
System.IO.StreamWriter sw;
sw = System.IO.File.AppendText(LogFilePath);
sw.WriteLine("Write Something");
sw.Close();
```

Comment: I don't really want to download the file, append to it, then upload it, below code worked but my credentials are visible to WireShark:
```c#
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@"Hello World.");
Uri target = new Uri("ftp://site.com/test.txt");
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(target);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.AppendFile;
request.ContentLength = data.Length;

request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("name", "pass");
using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```

Comment: Then I would suggest you to use SFTP protocol if possible. SharpSSH can do SFTP. This might solve your credential visibility issue in WireShark.

Comment: SharpSSH is dead project, do not use it.

Comment: Use this instead : https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET

Comment: @KhaledMdTuhidulHossain
My FTP server doesn't allow SFTP (port 22), only FTP/FTPS (port 21) .

Comment: @MartinPrikryl My FTP server doesn't allow SFTP (port 22), only FTP/FTPS (port 21) .

Answer (score 0):

WinSCP [`OverwriteMode.Append`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_transferoptions#overwritemode) is supported with SFTP protocol only.

---

If you want to use encrypted FTPS with `FtpWebRequest`, just set [`FtpWebRequest.EnableSsl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest.enablessl).
See [FTPS (FTP over SSL) in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4331665/850848#56888555).

Also, as you are setting `TlsHostCertificateFingerprint` in WinSCP, it seems that your server is using self-signed certificate. Then you might need this with `FtpWebRequest`:
[FtpWebRequest "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11586206/850848#66776112)

Comment: Thanks about WinSCP, but EnableSsl throws this:
`Message=The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.`

Comment: Ok, and did you try to google it? [FtpWebRequest "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11586206/850848#66776112).

Comment: Yes, it requires adding a X509 or whatever certificate, but the procedures look very complex.

Comment: I do not understand. What is complex?