# How to call HTTPS web service method from a .net console application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, https, asmx

I have an ASP.net web application.  It sits at https://www.example.com/Private.

I would like to create a .net console application that calls a web method on my ASP.net web application at https://www.example.com/Private/DataCall.

How do I program my .net console application to securely call the web method over HTTPS?

I have done this before in plain HTTP, but for this application, secure communication is essential.

Answer (score 2):

```
Uri uri = new Uri(url);
WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri);   
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, cert, chain, ssl) => true;
WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
ReadFrom(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
```

[How do I use WebRequest to access an SSL encrypted site using https?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560804/how-do-i-use-webrequest-to-access-an-ssl-encrypted-site-using-https)