# Power Shell Web Scraping SSL/TSL Issue

Tags: html, powershell, web-scraping

I am wanting to run a web scraping script on a server.

The current script collects the html on the specified page.

```
$url = "http://websms"
 [net.httpWebRequest] $request = [net.webRequest]::create($url)
 [net.httpWebResponse] $response = $request.getResponse()
 $responseStream = $response.getResponseStream()
 $sr = new-object IO.StreamReader($responseStream)
 $result = $sr.ReadToEnd()

 $result
```

This works fine on a typical web page. However I am wanting to run it on a servers admin page which of course requires a login.

I thought before I attempt to login I will try and scrape the login page of the server. Running the above script I get the following result.

```
   Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."
At C:\temp\web3.ps1:3 char:56
+  [net.httpWebResponse] $response = $request.getResponse <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Any idea of how to get around this issue or perhaps if you could point me a different direction so I can scrape elements from the admin html page of the sever.

Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This one liner will ignore SSL certificate errors:

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
```

Errors regarding self-signed untrusted certificates, mismatching names or expiration will be ignored after this is executed.

Comment: And to restore, just execute `[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = $null`

Comment: This is answer no longer works, see reason and workaround [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15841856/1254222)

Answer (score 0):

Use [this brilliant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/561242/712649):

```
public bool AcceptAllCertifications(object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certification, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    return true;
}
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias, Can that be converted to a Power Shell Script format?

Comment: Just compile it from source when running in PoSH, as here: http://poshcode.org/624