# Powershell HTTPS REST api GET/POST

Tags: .net, rest, powershell, https

I am attempting to test a very simple powershell script to get/post data from an internal ticketing site.  I am running into an issue that appears to be related to the SSL certificate needed.  Can someone please help me understand what code I need to add to make this work?

Thanks

**Error returned**: Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."

Current Code:

```
 $url = "https://username:password@IPADDRESS/ticket"
 $command = get-content jsonfile.json

 $bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($command)
 $web = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
 $web.Method = "POST"
 $web.ContentLength = $bytes.Length
 $web.ContentType = "application/json"
 $stream = $web.GetRequestStream()
 $stream.Write($bytes,0,$bytes.Length)
 $stream.close()

 $reader = New-Object System.IO.Streamreader -ArgumentList
 $web.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()
 $reader.ReadToEnd()
 $reader.Close()
```

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917875/power-shell-web-scraping-ssl-tsl-issue/9918045#9918045

Comment: Thanks that did help.  However, I soon discovered that Powershell v3 now has an Invoke-RestMethod cmdlet which does what I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get the functionality that I needed out of the new [Invoke-RestMethod](http://technet.microsoft.com/Library/hh849971.aspx) cmdlet introduced in Powershell v3.  This method allows you to include a certificate which I did and did not receive any errors.