# Powershell Setting Security Protocol to Tls 1.2

Tags: powershell, webclient

I am using this code

```
        $WebClient = New-Object system.net.webclient
        $WebClient.credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential -ArgumentList $username, $password
        $WebClient.Proxy = $null
        $WebClient.Headers.Add("COperation","MethodCall")
        $WebClient.Headers.Add("CMethod", "EnumerateInstances")
        $WebClient.Headers.Add("CObject", $NameSpace)
        $WebClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/xml")
        $System= $WebClient.UploadString($Url, "POST", $EnumMessage)
```

This works well. What I want to do is that set the Security Protocol to Tls1.2 or Tls1.1. Please help.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

setting this should change the protocol :

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;
```

PS : checked in powershell v5

Setting Multiple Security Protocols:

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11 -bor [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;
```

Comment: how to set that to use either Tls11 or Tls12?

Comment: $AllProtocols = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]'Ssl3,Tls,Tls11,Tls12'
        [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $AllProtocols
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36265534/invoke-webrequest-ssl-fails

Comment: Where can I find out what brackets [] mean?