# powershell command fails in .bat file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Hi I am running a powershell command inside a bat file and am getting the below error:

```
set "workdir=C:\myproject"
mkdir %workdir%
powershell -Command "(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.1/python-3.6.1.exe', '%workdir%\pyinstaller.exe')"
```

Error :

```
Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."
At line:1 char:1
+ (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://www.python.or ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `'%workdir%\pyinstaller.exe'` should be `"%workdir%\pyinstaller.exe"`. It is trying to save to %workdir%\pyinstaller.exe isntead of C:\myproject\pyinstaller.exe

Comment: Did you tried to google the error? This is not to complicated...
It fails on the download because the webpage uses https, you have to do a few extra steps

Comment: I've edited your question and removed the code that wasn't relevant, so you now only have a [mcve]. Including a big block of code isn't a good idea as a lot of people can't be bothered to read through to find the actual issue.

Comment: This looks like the answer to your problem. You should've Googled the error message ;)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41618766/powershell-invoke-webrequest-fails-with-ssl-tls-secure-channel#41618979

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to this : [Powershell Setting Security Protocol to Tls 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41674518/powershell-setting-security-protocol-to-tls-1-2?answertab=active#tab-top)
and
this : [Invoke-WebRequest SSL fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36265534/invoke-webrequest-ssl-fails?answertab=active#tab-top)

You can do something like this with a batch file :

```dos
@echo off
Title Download a file with Powershell
color 0A & Mode 60,3
set "workdir=C:\myproject"
If not exist %workdir% mkdir %workdir%
Set "URL=https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.1/python-3.6.1.exe"
Set "FileLocation=%workdir%\pyinstaller.exe"
echo(
echo    Please wait a while ... The download is in progress ...
Call :Download %URL% %FileLocation%
echo Done
Explorer /n,/select,"%FileLocation%" & Exit
::**************************************************************************
:Download <url> <File>
Powershell.exe ^
$AllProtocols = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]'Ssl3,Tls,Tls11,Tls12'; ^
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $AllProtocols; ^
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('%1','%2')
exit /b
::**************************************************************************
```

---

You can also download a file with `Certutil` command with a batch file like this :

```dos
@echo off
Title Download a file with Certutil
color 0A & Mode 60,3
set "workdir=C:\myproject"
If not exist %workdir% mkdir %workdir%
Set "URL=https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.1/python-3.6.1.exe"
Set "FileLocation=%workdir%\pyinstaller.exe"
echo(
echo    Please wait a while ... The download is in progress ...
Call :Download %URL% %FileLocation%
echo Done
Explorer /n,/select,"%FileLocation%" & Exit
::------------------------------------------
:Download <url> <File>
Certutil.exe -urlcache -split -f %1 %2>nul
exit /b
::------------------------------------------
```