# Send-MailMessage : Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed

Tags: azure, smtp, sendgrid, azure-powershell

I used the below PowerShell script for sending email using Azure SendGrid account details. While executing the script, I am getting the error `Send-MailMessage : Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed`

PoweShell Script:

```
$Username ="xxxxx@azure.com"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "xxxx" -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $Username, $Password
$SMTPServer = "smtp.sendgrid.net"
$EmailFrom = "from@mail.com"
$EmailTo = "to@mail.com"
$Subject = "SendGrid test"
$Body = "SendGrid testing successful"

Send-MailMessage -smtpServer $SMTPServer -Credential $credential -Usessl -Port 587 -from $EmailFrom -to $EmailTo -subject $Subject -Body $Body
```

So, can anyone suggest me how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a networking connection issue, you may check the followings:

- If you can reach the SMTP port (587) on the server. You may use Telnet to test SMTP communication. Refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/mail-flow/test-smtp-with-telnet?view=exchserver-2019#step-3-use-telnet-on-port-25-to-test-smtp-communication).
- If you have typed the correct parameters like credentials.

For more information, it's recommended to [use API Keys provided by SendGrid to send emails](https://4bes.nl/2020/01/19/send-email-from-powershell-with-sendgrid/) instead of sending passwords over the script.

Comment: I'm trying to run this command on `mac` os `Test-NetConnection` to know the information of `smtp.sendgrid.net` connection. But I'm getting the error `Not able find the command Test-NetConnection`

Comment: How to test connectivity of smtp server on `mac` os instead of using Telnet?

Comment: Try `nc -vz (your router's IP address) (port)` in the terminal. More details [here](https://www.wikihow.com/Check-if-a-Port-Is-Opened)

Comment: Is there any alternative approach for sending email with recent deployment details of Azure resources?

Comment: Have you tried the method in my shared [link](https://4bes.nl/2020/01/19/send-email-from-powershell-with-sendgrid/)?

Comment: Thanks @Nancy, it is working with send grid api key instead of username and password

Comment: Nancy, I am able to send email with send grid api key by following this [link](https://4bes.nl/2020/01/19/send-email-from-powershell-with-sendgrid/). But I want to send email to multiple receivers. So, can you please suggest me how to add multiple email addresses in the `to` section.

Comment: Try to use           "to"      = @(
                @{
                    "email" = "exa1@mp.le"
                    "name"  = "Receiving party"
                },
                 @{
                    "email" = "exa2@mp.le"
                    "name"  = "Receiving party"
                }

            )?

Comment: Yes it is working. But I'm looking the array format for passing list of email addresses.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this error (in non-Azure environment) by changing the security protocol to TLS 1.2:

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;
```

Details: [Powershell Setting Security Protocol to Tls 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41674518/powershell-setting-security-protocol-to-tls-1-2)

Related: [SmtpException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228644/smtpexception-unable-to-read-data-from-the-transport-connection-net-io-connect)

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks for saving hours of frustration 