# TLS version issue is being raised while connecting to AzureAD using the Azure Functions

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-ad-powershell-v2

I have deployed an Azure function app, While using the command Connect-AzureAD in one of the function is throwing the error "You are using TLS version 1.0, 1.1 and/or 3DES cipher which are deprecated to improve the security posture of Azure AD"

Though the function App

- has minimum tls version of 1.2
- the .NET framework is 4.8.x
- the other services like storage account etc. associated with the
  function app were using minimum TLS version of 1.2.

Function App details

Function runtime: Powershell

runtime version: 3.8.2.0

Any help regarding this issue would be helpful

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/enable-support-tls-environment?tabs=azure-monitor

Comment: Could you try adding this commad before the `Connect-AzureAD` command: `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12`

Comment: Hi @Thomas, Thank you that command worked. Can you let me know what was the logic behind adding this command. And also it would be helpful if I can get any documentation regarding this for reference. Thanks

Comment: You can check this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls#if-your-app-targets-net-framework-47-or-later-versions. I imagine the default value is not tls1.2 at the server level so you have to manually add that.

Comment: There are some post related to that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36265534/invoke-webrequest-ssl-fails

Comment: @AnandaBhavaniGedela where are you running this code? The only way to get such an error is to run on an unsupported and unpatched OS, eg Windows 7 or old versions of Windows Server. All supported OS versions use TLS1.2. If your *Azure Function* is trying to use anything less than TLS1.2, it's an infrastructure bug that should be fixed by Azure Support. Hard-coding the TLS version *prevents* you from using better algorithms like TLS1.3 found on Windows 11 and ... the Linux distros used to run many Azure services

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am running this code on Azure function environment provided while deploying the azure function app. The os version it is providing is OS version: Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.14393.0

Comment: Using what settings? According to [this similar question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/938474/tls-verion-error-in-azure-function.html) the TLS version is a configurable setting.

Comment: Yes, I had configured to TLS1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Kudu console, you could check the existing SecurityProtocol:

```
PS C:\home> [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol
Ssl3, Tls
```

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls#if-your-app-targets-net-framework-47-or-later-versions) :

> ServicePointManager, using .NET Framework 4.7 and later versions, will use the default security protocol configured in the OS. To get the default OS choice, if possible, don't set a value for the ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol property, which defaults to SecurityProtocolType.SystemDefault.
>
> Because the SecurityProtocolType.SystemDefault setting causes the ServicePointManager to use the default security protocol configured by the operating system, your application may run differently based on the OS it's run on. For example, Windows 7 SP1 uses TLS 1.0 while Windows 8 and Windows 10 use TLS 1.2.

According to the documentation, you could try setting the security protocol to system default by adding this command at the beginning of your script:

```powershell
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::SystemDefault
```

Alternatively, it not working you could force using specific version:

```
[Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
[Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls13
```

Comment: This doesn't "force" the use of TLS1.2, it *prevents* the use of TLS1.3 or better. That's what quote you included says. It says that in all *supported* OSs TLS1.2 will be the default

Comment: An Azure Function trying to use a deprecated algorithm is an infrastructure bug that should be fixed by Azure Support. Downgrading security isn't a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Got this error as well, the weird part was that when running the command `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol` it looked like I was using `Tls12`.

Error:

> Error Acquiring Token: AADSTS1002016: You are using TLS version 1.0,
> 1.1 and/or 3DES cipher which are deprecated to improve the security postur e of Azure AD. Your TenantID is:
> 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000. Please refer to
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2161187 and conduct needed
> actions to remediate the issue. For further questions, please contact
> your administrator

Got it working by first setting TLS to 1.3 like this:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls13
```

This gave me an exception when trying to connect.

Then I used the command below to set it back to `Tls12` and then everything worked:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading the `httpRuntime targetFramework` attribute in the web.config from 4.5.2 to 4.8 solved it for me.