# Invoke-RestMethod - Ignore Self Signed Certs

Tags: rest, powershell, self-signed, powershell-5.0

It seems like this question has been asked and answered, but so far every solution I come across does not help. I'm writing a PowerShell script to run some REST API's to get usage information. My script breaks immediately just trying to communicate to the server. For testing sake, I'm doing a very simplistic command:

```
Invoke-RestMethod 'https://server:4443/login'
```

It returns with this error:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
```

I can run the same command but with URL google.com and I get a valid return, so I know the command is working generally speaking.

If I run the curl equivalent on the server itself, things complete as expected. Here's a snippet of the verbose output of the curl command:

```
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.0 / DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
* Server certificate:
*        subject: CN=localhost
*        start date: 2016-03-22 21:48:57 GMT
*        expire date: 2026-03-20 21:48:57 GMT
*        issuer: CN=localhost
*        SSL certificate verify result: self signed certificate (18), continuing anyway.
```

I'm only assuming this is a self signed cert issue based upon searching the fairly generic error PowerShell returns.

I've tried:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
```

and other similar methods (complex functions) to help ignore certificate issues with no luck.

I'm running PowerShell 5 in case that helps.

I'm decent with PowerShell code but this is my first time trying Invoke-RestMethod, so maybe I'm missing something. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you miss your credentials if the webserver requires auth (`-Credential`). Or you need to specifiy `-Method` parameter `post` or` `get`. Its hard to tell if we don't know what your server is expecting.

Comment: My apologies for not giving full information upfront. I pass credentials via headers. I've tried to explicitly call the method too.

Answer (score 27):

This will also work in later versions of powershell with invoke-restmethod/webrequest. It avoids the requirement for a runspace by implementing the handler as native .net:

```
if (-not("dummy" -as [type])) {
    add-type -TypeDefinition @"
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

public static class Dummy {
    public static bool ReturnTrue(object sender,
        X509Certificate certificate,
        X509Chain chain,
        SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; }

    public static RemoteCertificateValidationCallback GetDelegate() {
        return new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(Dummy.ReturnTrue);
    }
}
"@
}

[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = [dummy]::GetDelegate()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Worked like a charm. The proposed answer is probably more complete, but a lot more code to maintain. Your solution worked prefectly. Thanks

Comment: The above worked great for me, but in addition I also had to add the code in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41618979/908316

Comment: Wow, it works. And this is so much easier than adding a "--insecure" to cURL. Thank you PowerShell for making our life this easy. Sorry did I say that out loud? ;p

Comment: lifesaving. actually lifesaving

Answer (score 14):

If after @x0n answer, you still have the problem, try add before Request/Rest this

`[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol =[System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12`

Working script for me:

```
if (-not ([System.Management.Automation.PSTypeName]'ServerCertificateValidationCallback').Type)
{
$certCallback = @"
    using System;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Security;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
    public class ServerCertificateValidationCallback
    {
        public static void Ignore()
        {
            if(ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback ==null)
            {
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += 
                    delegate
                    (
                        Object obj, 
                        X509Certificate certificate, 
                        X509Chain chain, 
                        SslPolicyErrors errors
                    )
                    {
                        return true;
                    };
            }
        }
    }
"@
    Add-Type $certCallback
 }

[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;
[ServerCertificateValidationCallback]::Ignore()

Invoke-WebRequest https://*YOUR URI*
```

Comment: this works for me on a Windows Server 2016 Box + PowerShell 5 (PSVersion                      5.1.14393.693)

For PowerShell 6+ use the -SkipCertificateCheck flag of Invoke-WebRequest

Comment: also look for https://stackoverflow.com/a/55246366/1358289 for a pure powershell solution to this problem

Comment: Thank you for adding a complete sample to know where to put the magic code.

Answer (score 13):

i know this is old, but it still came up when i had this question with out actually checking.  google first right?

Try this:

```
invoke-restMethod -SkipCertificateCheck -uri 'https://server:4443/login' -etc..etc..etc..
```

got it here via google: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-6

Comment: the question is marked for 5.0, the documentation you are referring to is for version 6.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and my PS version was 5.1, I initially used `[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12`

But anything below `Powershell6` please use the certificate policy from below link : 
https://gist.github.com/rchaganti/aae721ebccd25eaab0b8b3dd67ad4b9b

It works like charm. Thanks to Ravi Chaganti.

Comment: Works for me: [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

Powershel: 5.1.19041.2364

Answer (score 0):

I have been fighting this same issue for awhile now. I tried several variations of such scripts as what's already been posted in this thread. I was surprised to discover that by taking the same script and running it on my own workstation instead of in my testing environment that it worked.

In the end, I found out that by simply running the script in my test environment using elevated credentials (Run as administrator) that it worked without the SSL/TLS error.