# Downloading a file with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a URL to a CSV file which, in a browser, I can download and open without issue.

I'm trying to download this file using PowerShell without success. I tried using `Invoke-WebRequest`, `Start-BitsTransfer` and using a webrequest object but no luck there.

Comment: I stranded here when looking for a way to download from https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B78A_rsP6RDSVjBTa1ZUSXBGYzA/edit - the accepted answer helped me to find https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B78A_rsP6RDSVjBTa1ZUSXBGYzA&export=download - I know that this is not for this excact question but hope it could be an equally huge help to somebody else landing here.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

`Invoke-WebRequest` comes with a parameter to store its result in a file: `-OutFile`

```
Invoke-WebRequest $myDownloadUrl -OutFile c:\file.ext
```

If you need authorization before you can send a request like this:

```
Invoke-WebRequest $myAuthUrl /* whatever is neccesary to login */ -SessionVariable MySession
Invoke-WebRequest $myDownloadUrl -WebSession $MySession
```

To determine the layout of the form where the login happens, you can use Invoke-WebRequests return object. It'll collect information about forms and fields on the HTML (might be Windows only). Mileage of logging in may vary with things like Two-Factor-Auth active or not. Probably you can create some secret link to your file which does not need Auth or possibly google allows you to create a private access token of some sort, which can be send aus Authorization-Header alongside your request.

Comment: Works fine here .. CSV with No headers and one row with three test-entries

Comment: @JustAGuy: It works with (at least) Windows PowerShell v5.1 / PowerShell Core v6.1.0-preview.3. If it doesn't work for you, please add details about your environment to your question.

Comment: @JustAGuy This does work here also, you may not have rights to write to `C:\file.ext` try `Invoke-WebRequest 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1soyIpcac2hOb-5AdImm1LNCFs9jFiiyMhuqCayfpxSw/export?format=csv' -OutFile '$($Env:temp)\test.csv'` to store the file in the temp folder.

Comment: I have major 5 minor 1 installed. How can I tell if it's 5.1?
On my station it ends up as core html and not the actual file.

Comment: Have you quoted the URL? Perhaps there is a problem?
$PSVersionTable tells you the Versions

Comment: My apologies. I've put in the correct URL. This seems to work only with a new one for some reason. Try with this new one and tell me what you get.

Comment: Well - that is pretty simple: You get an authorization page - the link is protected and OutFile does as asked and saves the file (which is an html page containing some login)

Comment: You wouldnt happen to know how I can perform a login by a chance, right? Maybe grab a cookie from the browser?

Comment: You have to analyze the Page - Invoke-WebRequest can help (it reads forms and form fields) - I think the Docs from MS have a example for that.

Answer (score 36):

**TLDR answers***:

**Method 1a**, by default synchronous**

```
Invoke-WebRequest $url -OutFile $path_to_file
```

(if you get error *"...Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."* see [Powershell Invoke-WebRequest Fails with SSL/TLS Secure Channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41618766/powershell-invoke-webrequest-fails-with-ssl-tls-secure-channel))

**Method 1b (for JSON/XML data)**, by default synchronous**

```
Invoke-RestMethod $url -OutFile $path_to_file
```

This method is a wrapper around `Invoke-WebRequest`, but provides some additional formatting of JSON results. (See documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.4) and [here](https://www.truesec.com/hub/blog/invoke-webrequest-or-invoke-restmethod).)

**Method 2**, by default synchronous**

```
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url, $path_to_file)
```

**Method 3**, asynchronous and may be much slower than the other two but is very gentle on bandwidth usage (it uses the [BITS service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_Intelligent_Transfer_Service)).

```
Import-Module BitsTransfer
Start-BitsTransfer -Source $url -Destination $path_to_file
```

**Notes:**

*: This answer is for those that google  for "how to download a file with PowerShell".

**: Read the help pages if you want asynchronous downloading

Comment: I would guess that you were downvoted for not 'solving' the problem the user had. They indicated they had already tried the three methods you've suggested. Sounds like they were getting a login.html instead of a file.csv. They didn't specify that issue in their original question which they should have. However, it also seems like you didn't carefully read their question details and the other answer conversation before answering an already answered question. I've upvoted as your answer is helpful in similar contexts (but not this user's specific one).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response duct_tape_coder! Your time is greatly appreciated. Indeed my answer was more towards the Google reader that searched for "how to download with powershell" than to the original author. There's a conflict here and I can understand the POV for downvoting. I also noticed that it is already answered but I love terse (TLDR) answers so I often add them to help others with similar taste.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I used Method 3 because Core server throw back that Internet Explorer isn't available when using invoke-* variations

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = "https://www.somedomain.com/file.bin"
$dest = "C:\temp\testfiles.bin"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -OutFile $dest
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

For a while now I've been using a PS script to download PowerBI bi-monthly and using the BITS,  it's been pretty solid and now so much stronger now since I removed the `-Asynchronous` at the end of the `Start-BitsTransfer`

```
$url = "https://download.microsoft.com/download/8/8/0/880BCA75-79DD-466A-927D-1ABF1F5454B0/PBIDesktopSetup.exe"
$output = "%RandomPath%\PowerBI Pro\PBIDesktopSetup.exe"
$start_time = Get-Date

Import-Module BitsTransfer
Start-BitsTransfer -Source $url -Destination $output

#Commented out below because it kept creating "Tmp files"
#Start-BitsTransfer -Source $url -Destination $output -Asynchronous
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).