# How to re-direct download destination with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have a daily running Powershell script which downloads a csv file from a site.

the code is :

```
$oppo_url = "https://itisawebsite?export=1&enc=UTF-8&xf=csv"
Start-Process $oppo_url
```

`Start-Process` will invoke Chrome which is my default browser and download the csv to my local `Download` folder, but I want the process to download the file to a designated folder, would it be possible?

I tried to add `-WorkingDirectory 'C:\Users\myfolder\` but it didn't work.

Comment: Why not download the file using PowerShell instead of using Chrome for that? Examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51225598/downloading-a-file-with-powershell), or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41618766/powershell-invoke-webrequest-fails-with-ssl-tls-secure-channel/41618979#41618979)

Comment: While I agree that keeping it all in PS is a good idea, another option would be to move the file (Move-Item) after the download.

Answer (score 0):

Use [BITS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/bitstransfer/start-bitstransfer?view=win10-ps) its used internally to download stuff in the background, but you can use it as a simple file downloader:

`Start-BitsTransfer -Source "https://itisawebsite?export=1&enc=UTF-8&xf=csv" -Destination "c:\path\to\yourfiles\itisawebsite.csv"`

You can make it run as a background job by adding `-Asynchronous` and catch the return value from `Start-BitsTransfer` or use `Get-BitsTransfer` to check on the status of the downloads.

(Those `&` should really be `&amp;` but ive left it exactly as your example)

Answer (score 0):

There are two Chrome extensions i have seen, but there might be more. These are, Downloads Router and RegExp Download Organizer. Where you should be able to specify which filetype, and then the `.csv` file can be downloaded to a specific folder you specify.

When PowerShell opens Chrome, these settings should be used.