# Problems downloading Chocolatey

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

I'm trying to download the chocolatey software on my windows laptop (https://chocolatey.org/) using powershell.
My only problem is, that I get an error when I execute the download command line in powershell.
Whenever I execute the download command it says:

> This script contains malicious content and has been blocked by your
> antivirus software.

The script I'm using is:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force;
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; 
iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://community.chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
```

Comment: Do you have an anti-virus program running?

Comment: I have mcafee on my laptop but i dont have a license for it(it was already downloaded when i bought it). Other then that i didn't download any new anti-virus program.

Comment: Did you disable McAfee?  Please add the script you are using to the question.

Comment: I can't open mcafee. When i open it, it asks me for an activation key.

Comment: The script i'm using :  Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://community.chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))

Comment: Please edit the question and add the script there instead of comments.  Can you look at Services to see if McAfee is running?  Do you have Windows Security running?

Comment: Also, have you tried `Invoke-WebRequest $url -OutFile $path_to_file`?

Comment: Seems like Windows Defender Firewall is running, and also some mcafee programs (firewall core service)

Comment: Try disabling them and see if it works.

Comment: This is propably because of `Invoke-Expression` (`iex`), which can be considered dangerous as you are running code from a potentially untrusted source. Download to file as previous commenter suggests, then run the file.

Comment: Here is how you can do the download:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51225598/downloading-a-file-with-powershell

Comment: McAfee is known to block the chocolatey installer, giving that specific message: https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/2132#issuecomment-720966342 . If it's unlicensed, I would recommend removing it...

Comment: Thanks everyone for commenting, the problem was indeed mcafee, i bought it and disabled real time scanning. After disabling real time scanning, the command executed just fine.