# Converting bash script to Powershell: wget to Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: bash, powershell, cookies, wget, invoke-webrequest

I'm trying to convert a relatively simple bash script to run in Windows. It uses wget to download a file from a site that requires a login name but no password. I have been bashing my head against invoke-webrequest in Powershell for some time.

Working script, lightly obfuscated:

## Login and grab the auth cookies & link

```bash
wget --save-cookies /tmp/cookie.txt --keep-session-cookies --post-data 'login=myusername' -O /tmp/session.output https://website.com/session
```

## Parse out the link and use the cookies to grab the digest

```bash
wget --load-cookies /tmp/cookie.txt -O "/home/user/filename$(date "+%Y-%m-%d").pdf"  "https://website.com"
grep -o -E '/my-subscriptions/nnn/([^"#]+)pdf' /tmp/session.output
```

## Clean up

```bash
rm /tmp/cookie.txt
rm /tmp/session.output
```

Comment: Here is a rough conversion to PS of some old C# code that uses cookies - **not working code**.   `using namespace System.Net;[CookieContainer]$cookieJar = [CookieContainer]::new();$strURL = 'https://website.com/session';[string]$strResult = "";[HttpWebRequest]$hwRequest = [HttpWebRequest]([WebRequest]::Create($strURL));$hwRequest.CookieContainer = $CookieJar;$hwRequest.KeepAlive = $true;[HttpWebResponse]$hwResponse = [HttpWebResponse]$hwRequest.GetResponse();[StreamReader]$sr = [StreamReader]::new($hwResponse.GetResponseStream());$strResult = $sr.ReadToEnd();$sr.Close();return $strResult;`

Comment: Same concept with Powershell ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51225744/11954025)).  Where are you getting hung up at?  Please post the code for your Invoke-WebRequest attempt

Comment: I got mad at Invoke-Webrequest, now I'm trying with Windows curl command (not curl in PS which is an alias for Invoke-Webrequest). 

I think the first statement is: 

curl https://website.com/session --data "login=mylogin" -L -c c:\temp\cookies.txt -o "c:\Temp\session.txt"

But when I try to retrieve the page I get a size 0 file (forget the regex for now):

curl -c c:\temp\cookies.txt -o c:\temp\myfilename.pdf https://website.com/my-subscriptions/usn/dfa30360-16db-013b-e99c-327f1c57592d.pdf

Am I wrong about how curl handles cookies? The command completes ok.

Comment: I'm almost there! -b to load cookies instead of -c. This works:  

curl -b c:\temp\cookies.txt -o c:\temp\nyt.pdf https://website.com/file.pdf   

Now I just need to figure out the grep to findstr translation. The original:  

`wget --load-cookies /tmp/cookie.txt -O "/tmp/myfile.pdf"  "https://website.com\`grep -o -E '/my-subscriptions/usn/([^"#]+)pdf' /tmp/session.output\`"`;  

I don't think I need the regex since I haven't seen " or # in a filename yet. ...Admins, should this be a separate question now?