# Powershell Invoke-Restmethod aborted due to SSL/TLS Secure Channel (Smartsheets API)

Tags: powershell, ssl, smartsheet-api

I am  having trouble calling smartsheets api with powershell Invoke-Restmethod cmdlet.
The attached script has worked before. See error message regarding SSL/TLS below.

```
$apiKey = "**********"
$url = "https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets"
$get_headers = @{"Authorization" = "Bearer " + $apiKey}
$put_headers = @{}
$put_headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + $apiKey)
$put_headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $get_headers

Invoke-RestMethod : The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure 
channel.
```

Is there anyway around this error?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41618766/powershell-invoke-webrequest-fails-with-ssl-tls-secure-channel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Smartsheet API dropped support for TLS 1.0, which is the default for Powershell.

The [link Palansen shared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41618766/powershell-invoke-webrequest-fails-with-ssl-tls-secure-channel) above has some good solutions. Basically, you'll need to tell Powershell to use TLS 1.2 when invoked.