# Test a website(www.testwebsite.com) from a specific remote machine

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, haproxy

HAProxy uses below option to request a specific URL on a specific machine to perform actions like bringing it status to DOWN or UP.
I am looking for a way to test that same website on remote machine from local.

ping from CMD checks either for hostname or the endpoint. And the host url I am trying to test is running on port 80 along with other host urls on the same port. So i am unable to test my specific url.

`option httpchk GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\ www.testwebsite.com`

Any solution for windows platform would be fine.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So a `wget` or `Invoke-WebRequest`?

Comment: @CodeCaster
I tried both of them and I am facing an error "Invoke-WebRequest : The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."

Comment: Try using `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12` above your `Invoke-WebRequest` line. This post has folks saying that Tls1.0 is used by default https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41618766/powershell-invoke-webrequest-fails-with-ssl-tls-secure-channel