# Powershell Script to download a file from HTTPS website using

Tags: powershell

I need to download a file daily from a website where date will passed. I tried using following code -

```
$url = "https://www.theocc.com/webapps/threshold-securities?reportDate=20190730"
$output = "C:\Users\Himanshu.Vats\Downloads\"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $output
```

But it is giving error -

> Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
>       At line:3 char:1
>       + Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $output
>       + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>           + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
>           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Comment: I tried this also -
$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebClient.DownloadFile("https://www.theocc.com/webapps/threshold-securities","C:\Users\Himanshu.Vats\Downloads\") and this giving error -

Comment: Please see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41618766/powershell-invoke-webrequest-fails-with-ssl-tls-secure-channel/41618979#41618979 (ie. try setting `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 'Tls11,Tls12'` before calling `Invoke-WebRequest`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell Invoke-WebRequest Fails with SSL/TLS Secure Channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41618766/powershell-invoke-webrequest-fails-with-ssl-tls-secure-channel)

Answer (score 1):

It's because your path is not a path file (you have a '\' to end path)

try this:

```
$url = "https://www.theocc.com/webapps/threshold-securities?reportDate=20190730"
$output = "C:\Users\Himanshu.Vats\Downloads\result.csv"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $output
```