# Invoke-WebRequest permanent error of an unexpected error occurred on a send

Tags: powershell, scom

using PowerShell v5.1 on windows server 2016, for monitoring the availability of the following CrowdStrike Cloud Endpoint: https://ts01-b.cloudsink.net, with a dedicated proxy in our organization:

```
$URLAddress = "https://ts01-b.cloudsink.net"
$ProxyAddress = "http://proxyout.dev:8080"

$response = $null
$errorcode = $null

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "tls12, tls11, tls"


try
{
$request = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URLAddress -Method Get -UseBasicParsing -DisableKeepAlive -MaximumRedirection 0 -Proxy $ProxyAddress -ProxyUseDefaultCredentials

$response = $request.StatusCode
Write-Host "Status Code -- $response"
}
catch
{
$errormessage = $_.Exception.Message
$errorcode = $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.Value__
}


IF ($response -eq '200')
{
IF ($errorcode -eq $null)
{
  Write-Host "url: ""$URLAddress"" is avalible. `nStatus Code: $response"

}
ELSE
{
  Write-Host "url: ""$URLAddress"" is avalible but porxy: ""$proxydev"" has an error, `nError Code: $errorcode `nError Message:`n$errormessage. `nStatus Code: $response"
}
}
ELSE
{
  Write-Host "url: ""$URLAddress"" is not avalible. `nStatus Code: $response `nError Code: $errorcode `nError Message:`n$errormessage"
}

$request.BaseResponse.Close()
```

But I'm experiencing a strange behavior with the above script, for some reason i will get a **permanent** *error* of:

The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

Even though when I'm running the script **locally on target server**, the script is working without any problems.

Running an analysis using SSL Report, i can verify that [ts01-b.cloudsink.net](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=ts01%2Db.cloudsink.net&latest) is using TLS version 1.2. so i don't need to bypass the SSL certificate check `[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}` which is something that i saw mentioned frequently in other Stack Overflow posts, like:

[Unexpected error occurred running a simple unauthorized Rest query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41897114/unexpected-error-occurred-running-a-simple-unauthorized-rest-query)

[Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71494506/invoke-webrequest-the-underlying-connection-was-closed-an-unexpected-error-oc)

It is worth mentioning that the problematic window server is used by all the other developers in the organization, which run their own PowerShell scripts frequently manually or schedules by using a monitoring agent named SCOM by Microsoft.

I'm struggling to understand the root cause of this problem, has anyone experienced this kind of issue?

Comment: What happens if you try the same url in a web browser on the broken server? (Using the same account as the script is running in)

Comment: @mclayton, when running the PowerShell script manually on the target server, the script works without any problem. same for accessing it manualy trhoug the browser.