# Invoke-WebRequest : The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. under TLS12

Tags: powershell, tls1.2, invoke-webrequest

I'm getting error:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

The command I'm running is okay on other servers. 
Most of the answers to this error is about security protocol. While, here is mine:

```
PS C:\>[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol
Ssl3, Tls11, Tls12
```

And I still get this error. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41618766/powershell-invoke-webrequest-fails-with-ssl-tls-secure-channel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell Invoke-WebRequest Fails with SSL/TLS Secure Channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41618766/powershell-invoke-webrequest-fails-with-ssl-tls-secure-channel)

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I already have Tls12 in the environment.

Comment: Are you sure you are setting the spaces in assign operator '=' by definition it doesn't work if you join it with the variables.

Comment: Copied the command you suggested, doesn't wok still.

Comment: To what URL are you are trying to access?

Comment: Investigating network connectivity issue. Possible firewall issue. The same command can access other web resources only not that particular resource is not reachable.