# Powershell measuring connection time to a website

Tags: powershell

I have the following PowerShell Script, found and modified some time ago, however after checking and testing it in the past, I put this project away and wanted to check again now. However, the script should check a given website and tell how long it took to reach etc, but when I want to check with an internal website it is not working and constantly showing the cells with red color and error 200, however, external website like google or Facebook are measurable by the script.
Here is the script:

```
$URLListFile = "C:\Users\***\Desktop\websites.txt" 
$URLList = Get-Content $URLListFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$Result = @()

  Foreach($Uri in $URLList) {
  $time = try{
  $request = $null
  $result1 = Measure-Command { $request = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri }
  $result1.TotalMilliseconds
  } 
  catch
  {
   $request = $_.Exception.Response
   $time = -1
  }  
  $result += [PSCustomObject] @{
  Time = Get-Date;
  Uri = $uri;
  StatusCode = [int] $request.StatusCode;
  StatusDescription = $request.StatusDescription;
  ResponseLength = $request.RawContentLength;
  TimeTaken =  $time; 
  }

}

if($result -ne $null)
{
    $Outputreport = "<HTML><TITLE>Website Availability Report</TITLE><BODY background-color:peachpuff><font color =""#99000"" face=""Microsoft Tai le""><H2> Website Availability Report </H2></font><Table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0><TR bgcolor=gray align=center><TD><B>URL</B></TD><TD><B>StatusCode</B></TD><TD><B>StatusDescription</B></TD><TD><B>ResponseLength</B></TD><TD><B>TimeTaken</B></TD</TR>"
    Foreach($Entry in $Result)
    {
        if($Entry.StatusCode -ne "200")
        {
            $Outputreport += "<TR bgcolor=red>"
        }
        else
        {
            $Outputreport += "<TR>"
        }
        $Outputreport += "<TD>$($Entry.uri)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.StatusCode)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.StatusDescription)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.ResponseLength)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.timetaken)</TD></TR>"
    }
    $Outputreport += "</Table></BODY></HTML>"
}

$Outputreport | out-file C:\Users\***\Desktop\Test.htm
Invoke-Expression C:\Users\***\Desktop\Test.htm
```

Also attaching the picture about the result. Would you be able to help me why internal websites can not be measured, how should this script be modified so it can work? [Website Availability Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H88vp.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3F2U0.png)

Comment: What does the PowerShell comand: `(iwr "https://www.facebook.com").StatusCode` print if you use an internal site?

Comment: What is the content of the url list file?

Comment: @HelpingHand I have attached the result at the bottom of the description

Comment: It if you just run the line I posted for an internal url what happens?

Comment: There's an issue establishing SSL connection, you can try [that solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41618979/9902555) or just dig into the SSL settings of the website (verify that you trust the root CA for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so adding this line solved my issue, as the webpage is not accepting SSL 1.0 but 1.2 only connection. [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;