# Problem downloading file using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have this simple script that works on a laptop:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol
[enum]::GetNames([Net.SecurityProtocolType])

$url = "https://www.contextures.com/SampleData.zip"

wget -Uri $url -OutFile "C:\temp\temp.zip"
```

But when I'm trying to run it on a server I'm always getting this error:

> wget : The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure
> channel.

Any ideas what might be causing this? Any help would be appreciated.

I already tried this and still getting the same error message:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41618766/powershell-invoke-webrequest-fails-with-ssl-tls-secure-channel *PowerShell by default uses TLS 1.0 while most sites require TLS 1.2*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell Invoke-WebRequest Fails with SSL/TLS Secure Channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41618766/powershell-invoke-webrequest-fails-with-ssl-tls-secure-channel)

Comment: @SPTutors It results with the same error message

Comment: @hod Are you sure you're using `Invoke-WebRequest` and not `wget.exe` by accident?

Comment: @Tomalak Yes I am. I tried `Invoke-WebRequest` and `wget`, same result.

Comment: I can download the file no problem using `Invoke-WebRequest https://www.exaa.at/download/history/DSHistory2020.xls -OutFile DSHistory2020.xls`, without setting the `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol` beforehand. Could it be that there are some components (such as virus scanners or proxies) messing with your SSL connection?

Comment: @Tomalak Yes, I can do the same on my laptop, but can't figure what might be preventing me from downloading this on a server. Does Invoke-WebRequest have some properties/methods to check what might be causing this?

Comment: Your server might not have the necessary CA certificates in the root certificate list  to allow the connection. Can you download the file in Internet Explorer on the server?

Comment: I tried accessing it using IE, and am getting message that the "Proxy server isn't responding"

Comment: Are you actually using a Proxy server? If not, in IE, go `Tools -> Internet Options -> Connections -> LAN Settings` and uncheck the "Proxy server" checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Set it to TLS 1.2:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try with this example while adding
`$AllProtocols = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]'Ssl3,Tls,Tls11,Tls12';`

---

```
cls
$Folder = "$Env:Temp\DownloadFolder\"
# We create a SubFolder Named "DownloadFolder" in the temporary file %Temp% if it doesn't exists yet !
If ((Test-Path -Path $Folder) -eq 0) { New-Item -Path $Folder -ItemType Directory | Out-Null }

$urls=@('https://www.contextures.com/SampleData.zip',
'https://cdn2.unrealengine.com/Fortnite%2FBoogieDown_GIF-1f2be97208316867da7d3cf5217c2486da3c2fe6.gif'
)

$start_time = Get-Date
$AllProtocols = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]'Ssl3,Tls,Tls11,Tls12';
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $AllProtocols;

$i = 0
foreach($url in $urls)
{
    $i = $i + 1
    $output = $Folder + $url.Split("/")[-1]

Try {
        Write-Host "$i - Downloading" $output.Split("\")[-1] from $url
        (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url,$output)
    }

Catch

    {
        Write-Host "Error in : " $url -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Yellow
        Write-Host "Message: [$($_.Exception.Message)"] -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Yellow
        $i = $i - 1
    }
}

Write-Output "Time taken: $((Get-Date).Subtract($start_time).Seconds) second(s) to download $i files"
ii $Folder
```