# PowerShell Multi-Line String with Terraform Azure VM Extension

Tags: azure, powershell, automation, terraform

I'm building Terraform automation that deploys a windows VM and then has the VM download an executable to install an agent locally on it from a URL. I'm hitting the TLS / SSL secure channel issue when I use PowerShell within the Terraform Azure VM extension for Windows. I've identified the PowerShell commands I need to call to [stop the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41618766/powershell-invoke-webrequest-fails-with-ssl-tls-secure-channel). My issue is that I can't fit all of these lines into the "commandToExecute" successfully and then run Invoke-Webrequest with the URL and my additional command to silently install the agent. I've tried building them as locals using heredoc and then concatenating the variables but received ***"contains an invalid JSON invalid character ' r' in string literal"*** . I've tried using the FileURI option in the extension as well and putting a PowerShell script on Github for the VM to download and run, but getting the same SSL / TLS channel errors via this method. Below is an example of the code:

```
`locals {

  powershell_1 = <<EOT 
  "add-type @' 
  using System.Net; 
  using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates; 
  public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
      public bool CheckValidationResult(
          ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,
          WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) 
      {
        return true;
      }
  }
  '@
  
  [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy}"
  EOT
          
  powershell_2 = "Invoke-WebRequest -uri 'https://${var.guardi-aggr-ip}/windows_installer.exe?profile=azure' -outfile C:\\Windows\\Temp\\installer.exe"
  
  powershell_3 = "Invoke-Expression -Command 'C:\\Windows\\Temp\\Installer.exe /a ${var.guardi-aggr-ip} /p ${var.agent_install_password} /installation-profile azure'"
  
  powershell_config = "${local.powershell_1}; ${local.powershell_2}; ${local.powershell_3}"
}

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
      "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe -command "${local.powershell_config}
    }
    SETTINGS`
```

Is it possible to run a multi-line powershell command via the Terraform Azure extensions? Or would there be a better way to automate this with Terraform? I'm aware this can be done with local-exec and using WinRM but trying to avoid that scenario and not have to open additional firewall ports on the windows VMs deployed.

Comment: Do you still need additional information about that topic?