# Build python3 PGO without using additional closed source or bloated ...stuff

Tags: python, visual-studio, powershell, nuget, pgo

Forgive me but i'm a little out of my element here.

How can I build Python 3 without using closed source Nuget5 or the massive MSVS?
Is there a way to compartmentalize bits and pieces of this and only grab what I absolutely need, preferably using open utilities ?

My buddies original question is below (he's helping me through all this):

> We want to build python 3 (latest release) on windows for a xeon
> machine we are testing against nuclear and solar radiation. What build
> syntax would I use that would include PGO as well as remove source
> files and leave only the required files/folders (../lib, ../include,
> etc...) on a win7pro machine? (xeon) The machine will be doing a lot
> of mobile device testing. The build needs to be secure and geared
> towards working with devices over usb-c.
>
> Optimally a added install switch to have a shadow copy auto generate
> would be the best route in addition to that.

We ran into some issues however in the building process. As it seems NuGet is closed source ?
And we ran into some powershell errors as well. (see attached)

[https://ibb.co/VHk3mqR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRFtT.png)

Is there a way of compiling all this with little pomp and parade?

Thank you truly!

Comment: Take a look here for the PowerShell error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41618766/powershell-invoke-webrequest-fails-with-ssl-tls-secure-channel

Comment: [Since when has nuget been closed source?](https://github.com/nuget/nuget.client)

Comment: The latest version of NuGet doesn't seem to have a source and a asc files associated with it as far as we can see?

As for the earlier comment that only seems to fix part of the issue. Thank you all for trying though!

Comment: Was able to obviously fix the MSBUILD .NET issue, but is there no way of building python *PGO* without actually installing it?

Comment: VS IDE/MSBuild tool is big, yes, it is for projects and solutions and whole build. I’m not sure but does VS Code work for you? VS Code is lighter.

Comment: Thing is..., it seems the build code insists on trying to download the python binaries themselves. Am I missing something ?
Would love to just be able to build from scratch on windows using only .NET and VS C++ RD.