# Having trouble uploading large files with Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: powershell, vagrant

I am trying to use the Hashicorp Atlas restful api to upload box files into but I am running into problems when uploading large files.

I am currently using the following command which works with small files like 100mb but most box files are well over 4GB where I start to see the problem:

```
$Filename = "c:\box\mybox.box"
$uploadpath = "https://archivist.hashicorp.com/v1/object/example"
$Timeout = 86400 #24 hours
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uploadPath -Method Put -InFile $Filename -TimeoutSec $Timeout -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
```

The error:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\atlasbox\1.1.15\AtlasBox.psm1:642 char:5
+     Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uploadPath -Method Put -InFile $Filename  ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

If I use CURL command as per the documentation it works fine.

```
curl -X PUT --upload-file /path/to/my.box https://archivist.hashicorp.com/v1/object/example
```

Any idea how to make Invoke-RestMethod behave the same way curl does?

I can't take a dependency on curl because not all systems I run this on will have WSL installed and no curl.

Documentation for Atlas API is here: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/help/api/vagrant/box-providers

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it might be getting weird on the SSL cert? I would try some of the recommendations here to start with, definitely an oddity specific to those cmdlets though:

[Powershell v3 Invoke-WebRequest HTTPS error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696944/powershell-v3-invoke-webrequest-https-error)

Comment: this is only valid if you have not done this `[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidati‌​onCallback = {$true}`

Comment: After adding the solution from that thread I now get: Invoke-RestMethod : Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\atlasbox\1.1.21\AtlasBox.psm1:691 char:5
+     Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uploadPath -Method Put -InFile $Filename  ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-RestMethod], OutOfMemoryException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.OutOfMemoryException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand