# Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with Invoke-Webrequest from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ssl

When I try to use Invoke-WebRequest on https, I'm getting some weird error:

> Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

Here is my code:

```
   [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls
    $url = "https://X.X.X.X:4343/officescan/console/html/cgi/cgiChkMasterPwd.exe"
    $r = Invoke-WebRequest $url -SessionVariable office
```

Any advice for me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell v3 Invoke-WebRequest HTTPS error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696944/powershell-v3-invoke-webrequest-https-error)

Comment: See the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15841856/934946

Comment: Basically, if your SSL certificate is invalid or self-signed, you will have this error but you can "trust" all SSL certificate for your script so the error won't appear.

Comment: @SagePourpre , thank your advice, it's work ^^

Answer (score 19):

Of course it is an issue with an invalid certificate (autosigned?, expired?)
if using Powershell 7+ simply use the new parameter

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://trees.com/' -SkipCertificateCheck
```

if using Powershell 5.1 it is a bit harder:

```
$code= @"
        using System.Net;
        using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
        public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
            public bool CheckValidationResult(ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate, WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) {
                return true;
            }
        }
"@
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code -Language CSharp
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://trees.com/'
```

Comment: I added `using System;` and `Console.WriteLine(certificate.ToString(true));` and discovered a proxy performing a MITM on my WebRequest.

Answer (score 4):

A possible solution I have seen is this:

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
```

you can override the certification validation function to always return true.

Its much simpler than overriding CheckValidationResult.

[Credit](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-resolve-the-underlying-connection-was-closed-could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-the-ssl-tls-secure-channel-in-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;
$url = "https://X.X.X.X:4343/officescan/console/html/cgi/cgiChkMasterPwd.exe"
$r = Invoke-WebRequest $url -SessionVariable office
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try bypassing the PowerShell profile, in case there's something weird in there (my issue).

```
powershell -noprofile
```