# Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel From Powershell

Tags: powershell, ssl, ssl-certificate

when teamcity runs powershell script, that calls soap service with next certificate settings (from this link [Powershell v3 Invoke-WebRequest HTTPS error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696944/powershell-v3-invoke-webrequest-https-error) ) :

```
add-type @"
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
    public bool CheckValidationResult(
        ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,
        WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) {
        return true;
    }
}
"@
$AllProtocols = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]'Ssl3,Tls,Tls11,Tls12'
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $AllProtocols
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy
```

when it runs for the very first time by teamcity, it failed with an error:

```
"The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel." ---> System.Net.WebException: The 
  request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
     at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
     at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
     at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
     at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , network )
```

but when I run again script manually after teamcity, it works fine.
I'm confused why this can happen.

Comment: So manual works all the time and from teamcity it never works? Did you run it manually from the server where teamcity is deployed?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers , both answers are yes.

Comment: it both is running with the same user I assume? At that point, I'd start looking at procmon or network traces and work out the differences

Comment: Have you tried googling the error message itself? It will give you some pointers. One suggestions e.g. was `[ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 3072` for older .NET versions..

Comment: do you have some good articles about network tracing?

Comment: @marsze, I'm not sure, maybe .Net version is 3.1

Comment: I had a similar issue.  Enabled 1.0,1.1,1.2, and one page would fail.  That site only supported 1.0, and was fine with just 1.0 in protocols, but not all 3.  Worth a shot.