# Curl command to Powershell to get X-SDS-AUTH-TOKEN

Tags: powershell, rest

I run the below cUrl command to get an X-SDS-AUTH-TOKEN. Is there any way I can convert this to Powershell to be able to script it? I'm been playing around with it, but not having much success. Any help greatly appreciated.

curl -L -v -k https://172.31.110.16:4443/login -u username:password

Thanks

I've looked at a lot of articles online, but nothing seems to point in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer - ive no idea what X-SDS-AUTH-TOKEN is - but you appear to be performing a simple GET request with BASIC auth so...

Step 1 - understand the command you want to replicate - consult the [man page for Curl](https://www.mit.edu/afs.new/sipb/user/ssen/src/curl-7.11.1/docs/curl.html) and read about each of the arguments your passing to curl `-L` `-v` `-k` and `-u username:password`. In summary:

1. `-L` - this instructs Curl to follow redirects
2. `-v` - enable Curl's verbose output
3. `-k` - allows "insecure" SSL connections (self signed / expired / untrusted certificates)
4. `-u user:pwd` - pass username "user" and password "pwd" to the webpage

Step 2 - Powershell gives you a few options, but for a simple GET request take a look at [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest).

Comparing the default behavior of `Invoke-WebRequest` to `curl` you will find:

1. `Invoke-WebRequest` follows redirects by default
2. PowerShell provides a `-Verbose` switch with many commands, but this is not required
3. `Invoke-WebRequest` provides `-SkipCertificateCheck` in newer versions of powershell, but it can be achieved [via .Net for older versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696944/powershell-v3-invoke-webrequest-https-error). **This is a security risk** - make sure you understand the implications of bypassing certificate checks.
4. I think curl will do BASIC auth by default. `Invoke-WebRequest` has an `-Authentication` switch (but it requires a powershell credential object) - BUT you might find it easier to create an `Authorization` header yourself using the `-Headers` switch.

I'm not going to give you a full solution, but this should point you in the general direction. Good luck!