# Error [Invoke-WebRequest] in PowerShell Windows 11

Tags: powershell, rest, jira

just to clarify:
I'm trying to download Jira attachments by REST API using Power Shell. But I'm facing problem in the final step. The error is:

`Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
No line:64 caractere:2

- Invoke-WebRequest -Headers @{"Authorization"=$authorization} -uri $u ...
- ```
   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
  eption
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand`
  ```

This is my all PowerShell Script:

```
# Export all attachments from XML export of Jira

Function Get-Folder($initialDirectory)
{
 [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")|Out-Null

$foldername = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
 $foldername.Description = "Select a folder to store exported attachments"
 $foldername.rootfolder = "MyComputer"

if($foldername.ShowDialog() -eq "OK")
 {
 $folder += $foldername.SelectedPath
 }
 return $folder
}

# Jira Authorization
$cred=get-credential -Message "Enter you username and password to access Jira Cloud"
$user = $cred.username
$pass = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($cred.password))
$pair = "$($user):$($pass)"
$encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair))
$authorization = "Basic $encodedCreds"
$directory = Get-Folder

# You must create a filter and copy "export to XML" URL
$uri=read-host "Paste 'XML export' URL (Jira)"
$temp=$uri.Split("/")
$base_uri=$temp[0]+'//'+$temp[2]
$outfile="list.xml"

# This folder will be used to store all attachments, for each record (jira issue) will be created a folder 
# with the issue key and inside it will be stored all attachments
$directory="$directory\attachments"

Invoke-WebRequest -Headers @{"Authorization"=$authorization} -uri $uri -outfile $outfile

[xml]$Content = Get-Content .\list.xml
$Feed = $Content.rss.channel

ForEach ($msg in $Feed.Item){ 
 $idjira=$msg.key.'#text'
 if (Test-path "$directory\$idjira") {
 write-host "Folder $directory\$idjira exists"
 } else {
 write-host "Folder $directory\$idjira don´t exist, creating..."
 mkdir "$directory\$idjira"
 }
 ForEach ($attachment in $msg.attachments.attachment) {
 $idattachment=$attachment.id
 $nameattachment=$attachment.name
 $uri="$base_uri/secure/attachment/$idattachment/"
 if (test-path "$directory\$idjira\$nameattachment") {
 $outfile="$directory\$idjira\$idattachment.$nameattachment"
 $outfile=$outfile.Replace('[','').replace(']','')
 write-host "File [$directory\$idjira\$nameattachment] already exists, creating other version $outfile"
 } else {
 $outfile="$directory\$idjira\$nameattachment"
 $outfile=$outfile.Replace('[','').replace(']','') 
 write-host "Creating file $outfile" 
 }
 write-host "Downloading $uri to $outfile..."
 Invoke-WebRequest -Headers @{"Authorization"=$authorization} -uri $uri -outfile $outfile
 write-host "done"
 }
}
Remove-item ".\list.xml"
```

I've tried to apply all recomendations you've sent here: [Powershell v3 Invoke-WebRequest HTTPS error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696944/powershell-v3-invoke-webrequest-https-error)
But nothing it seems work. Someone knows how to fix this problem?

Try to download Jira attachments by REST API and I expect figure out how to solve Power Shell erro

Comment: I would ensure the `$uri` is correctly formatted before your request, but this is some troubleshooting you'd have to do. I recommend placing it inside a try/catch statement to  produce a more detailed error:
`try { Invoke-WebRequest -Headers @{"Authorization"=$authorization} -uri $uri -outfile $outfile; } catch { Write-Host $_.Exception.Response.StatusDescription; Write-Host $_.Exception.Message;}`

Comment: Thanks @AbrahamZinala, I've added a try/catch but give the same error "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden". Getting the $uri URL that generated for each attachment, and accessing him using any browser I have the attachment downloaded. It seems a simple thing but complicated to be solved hahaha :d

Comment: Tbh, I’d start with a much smaller and simpler script with hardcoded details just to get the authentication flow working - e.g. ```$user = “<hardcoded-username>”; $pass = “<hardcoded-password>”; $uri = “<hardcoded-uri>”; $auth = … calculate auth …; Invoke-WebRequest …```, then use a tool like Fiddler to check the http request matches the Jira documentation…

Comment: https://atlassianps.org/docs/JiraPS/