# Getting .aspauth cookie through https

Tags: asp.net, authentication, cookies, https

This worked well on http, but doesn't work on https.

```
private Cookie GetAuthCookie(string user, string pass)
    {
        var http = WebRequest.Create(_baseUrl+"Users/Login") as HttpWebRequest;
        http.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        http.Method = "POST";
        http.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        http.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        var postData = "UserName=" + user + "&Password=" + pass + "&RememberMe=true&RememberMe=false&ReturnUrl=www.google.com";
        byte[] dataBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        http.ContentLength = dataBytes.Length;
        using (var postStream = http.GetRequestStream())
        {
            postStream.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
        }
        var httpResponse = http.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        return httpResponse.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
    }
```

Comment: Its probably an SSL cert issue, see this question for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560804/how-do-i-use-webrequest-to-access-an-ssl-encrypted-site-using-https

Comment: I'll make an answer version to close the loop on this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its probably an SSL cert issue, you'll see this with accessing SSL via WebClient or WebRequest depending on the situation with your certificate issuer. See this prior [question for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560804/how-do-i-use-webrequest-to-access-an-ssl-encrypted-site-using-https) on how to get around this.