# MS Windows Service and https

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, https, windows-services

I have web site that has installed SSL so it is working under HTTPS with FirstData.com

Now I have to create MS Windows Service that should do the same things like website does under SSL.

So my question about to use SSL with MS Windows Service... Is it possible to do any clue?

I mean to use MS Windows Service somehow with https to interact with FirstData.com under SSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) class to make a request to a secure site.

An example would be

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri("https://www.example.com")) as HttpWebRequest;
```

However, do bear in mind that the secure sites might have invalid certificates. If you trust your endpoint and want to ignore 'certificate invalid' warnings, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/561242/326543) answer talks about how to do this.

Comment: New Question: What if I have to login first? How we can do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
System.Net.HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("https://mydomain.com/etc"));
```

Comment: Cool! Could u put some comments and suggestions as well, please?

Comment: New Question: What if I have to login first? How we can do it? Thank you!