# HttpWebResponse Returns 404 Error When Page Exists

Tags: c#, httprequest

I'm trying to write a small desktop application that will monitor a website through their API. I've never really done much work with APIs or WebRequests, so I'm unsure as to how to proceed with this error. After generating a requests, I try to GET the response from the page, but this returns a 404 error, even though if I navigate to the same URL in my browser it works fine. I have no idea how to get around this, and the research I've done on people who had the same problem hasn't helped me to understand it. Could someone explain to me what is happening at a basic level? My code has been posted below:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string sURL;
        sURL = @"https://habitrpg.com/api/v1/user";

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sURL);

        HttpWebResponse response = null;
        try
        {
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            resultText.Text = "Oh no!";
        }
        Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        string responseData = readStream.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

Comment: I got Error 401, Are you sure you are getting 404?

Comment: Yes, if I step through the code as it runs, the exception says that it's a 404 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should ignore `https` certificate, look at this question:

[How do I use WebRequest to access an SSL encrypted site using https?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560804/how-do-i-use-webrequest-to-access-an-ssl-encrypted-site-using-https)

Comment: I tried adding the lines that that question talks about, and I'm still getting a 404 error. All I had to do was add the ServicePointManager line, and define the Boolean he defines, right?

Comment: @SeanCogan This is next step, if you getting 404 that's mean: invalid url, invalid params or some headers also could be invalid. The simplest way to check difference with browser is `Fiddler`. Allow `https` traffic and make request in browser and with your program.