# Read web page html (HTTPS)

Tags: c#, html, winforms

I currently use a website tracking program which downloads the HTML code of a webpage. It then asks for two search strings which surround the target code you wish to monitor then does some other stuff etc etc.

My question is, how would I access the HTML code of a HTTPS site through windows forms (C#) so I can make my own program?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/560804/43846) might be helpful

Comment: Thank you kind sir. Hit the nail on the head. :)