# Making a HTTPS request using C# Smart Device Project .net 2.0

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, smart-device

I am working on a Windows Smart Device project. I want to send a HTTPS request to a API host to retrieve information.

The current code noted in the link below works perfectly on my trial on a Windows Form application:

[How do I use WebRequest to access an SSL encrypted site using https?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560804/how-do-i-use-webrequest-to-access-an-ssl-encrypted-site-using-https)

However, this does not work in a Smart Device application as I do not have access to `System.Net.Security` on the Smart Device project (In fact there is only `System.Net.Sockets` under `System.Net`, rendering me unable to use the same method for queries outside of non-SSL sites.

Is there a workaround for the same solution to be able to make HTTPS requests?

**EDIT:** I know that Google Maps is a bad example, especially when their API keys are insecurely sent over the HTTPS GET method usually and it is better to use a server to secure the requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer to my own problem.

I could create a C++ module to handle the HTTPS requests instead, and using C#'s pinvoke method to call the C++ module and returning the results.

Alternatively I could use make a server that handles HTTP requests like a middleman, similar to the C++ module. This server makes the HTTPS requests on behalf of the Smart Device Application to return the results.

TL;DR it is nothing much but just using the middleman approach to solve the problem since there is no function in the Smart Device Application template that could handle HTTPS requests.