# HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() returning 404: Not Found for a valid URL

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I'm making an app in unity and I need to download a file.
I'm using the following code to get header values:

```
    HttpWebRequest request =   (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(remoteFile);
    request.Method = "HEAD"; 

    HttpWebResponse resp = null;

        try {
            resp = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
      }catch (System.Exception e) { 
        Debug.LogWarning("ERROR: " + e);
        return;
      }
```

This code worked for some files, but I'm hosting a file on ge.tt, and it doesn't work on it.
The link I gave it starts the download immediately in chrome.

The error is:

```
ERROR: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckFinalStatus (System.Net.WebAsyncResult result)
```

Does anyone know why is this happening?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe the ge.tt doesn't support the HEAD verb and returns (incorrectly) a 404? try to do a plain GET.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've tried GET and I get a "request timed out".
This is very strange

Comment: maybe in url you're using "https:" instead of "http:"?

Comment: Yes, I am using https, when I try the url with http instead it gives the following error:
"Write: The authentication or decryption has failed."

Comment: Okay, I looked for the new problam and found a fix for it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The link was https, and when I changed it to http it game me an authentication error, so I followd [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560804/how-do-i-use-webrequest-to-access-an-ssl-encrypted-site-using-https) link and fixed it.