# how to get https files based on URL in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

In my requirement, I need to get the file from a URL. I tried, but it always throws a forbidden error. Please try to solve this problem. Please look in to my code.

```
var webRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://www.fda.gov/ucm/groups/fdagov-public/@fdagov-drugs-gen/documents/document/ucm509432.pdf");  
using (var response = webRequest.GetResponse())
   using (var content = response.GetResponseStream())
      using (var reader = new StreamReader(content))
      {
         var strContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
      }
```

Comment: Does the site require login or auth of some kind? You may need to construct a cookie or user with the right creds for ti to let you in.

Comment: are you handling the certificate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560804/how-do-i-use-webrequest-to-access-an-ssl-encrypted-site-using-https

Comment: we dont know any logins. they want to take the file based on URL.

Comment: Loads fine in Chrome here so no login required. Also given it's binary data (a PDF in this instance) why are you using `ReadToEnd` and treating it as a string?

Comment: yes but need to take that file and store in my DB but still i am not getting any file it throws always forbidden error

Comment: This works OK for me. Double-check your URL (for spaces etc.).

Comment: Works well. Make sure the URL is correct `WebRequest.Create("https://www.fda.gov/ucm/groups/fdagov-public/@fdagov-drugs-gen/documents/document/ucm509432.pdf")`

Comment: While I also get 403 Im behind a proxy ..

Comment: URL is correct. its open in browser

Comment: Im getting the same results as @chaitanya in the question it opens in a browser not in c# despite checking the url is one string etc

Comment: will you please modify my code @BugFinder

Comment: The problem is probably the HttpWebRequest class not supporting TLS1.2. Check my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I checked the response contents from the server, I realized that it is stating that the client needed to Support TLSv1.2.

To enable TLSv1.2 support, add the following line before creating the HttpWebRequest class: (Thanks BugFinder for the direct enumeration value tip)

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

I am posting the complete source code.

You can also see that I tested sending some headers to the server to see if the absence of one of them was the problem:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        HttpWebRequest webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.fda.gov/ucm/groups/fdagov-public/@fdagov-drugs-gen/documents/document/ucm509432.pdf") as HttpWebRequest;
        webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0) like Gecko";
        webRequest.Accept = "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*";
        webRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        webRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "tr-TR");
        webRequest.Headers.Add("DNT", "1");

        using (var
             response = webRequest.GetResponse())
        using (var content = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(content))
        {
            var strContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good catch although ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; should also be sufficient as its already defined

Comment: still it gives wrong content in StrContent var. not getting URL based content @BugFinder

Comment: Ok, did not focus on that part. ReadToEnd() returns string, while the content must be handled as binary. Converting the binary PDF data to string is no use I think.

Comment: will you please modify that @Oguz Ozgul

Comment: Your question is about how to overcome the 403 forbidden error. You can search stack overfow to learn how to treat binary content downloaded from a server.

Comment: i know hoe to convert binary to string but in this binary content is not correct as per my URL @OguzOzgul

Comment: please solve this problem. my question is i need to get URL content into string @OguzOzgul

Comment: Why a string? its a pdf - a PDF is not a string - what is the response you expect?

Comment: If you want to get the CONTENTS OF THE PDF as string, you need to use a library that converts pdf files to html / text etc. Check this open source solution for instance. https://github.com/spatie/pdf-to-text

Comment: will you please tell the where pdf content is there in which variable response,content,reader variables. @OguzOzgul

Comment: This working fine for me but it not working in IIS. will you please look into this once

Comment: the problem is solved. in hosting server they dont have permissions for Tls12 protocol. now solved thanks for helping me

Comment: You're welcome. I am glad that your problem is solved